# why there is no infinite loop when embedded class inherits the outer class

Tags: c++

```
template<typename... TA>
struct AAA
{
    template<typename TB>
    struct BBB : AAA<TA..., SomeClass<TB>>
    {}
};
```

I have seen the above code and have difficulties to understand the theory behind the code.

Question 1> Is there a specific concept that describe the usage of this pattern?
Any reference I can refer to?

Question 2> Why the definition of struct BBB doesn't cause infinite loop?

Thank you

Comment: No infinite loop because templates do not get instantiated until they're actually referenced in the context of a template instance. In order to get an infinite loop from this template declaration you need to write a C++ source file that is itself an infinite loop. Good luck!

Comment: C++ is going too far for my old brain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to think of an actual example of an instantiation.  A few cases should make it clear:

```
using Type1 = AAA<>::BBB<int>;
// Type1 baseclass is AAA<SomeClass<int>>

using Type2 = typename Type1::BBB<char>;
// Type2 baseclass is AAA<SomeClass<int>, SomeClass<char>
```

Etc.  Until you "reach inside" and ask for another instantiation, there are none.  For example, until Type2 is defined, nothing causes any instantiation of Type1::BBB for any set of X's.